# Vertically align these buttons

Tags: css, button, stylesheet

I am embedding a Twitter button and a LinkedIn profile button, side by side, using those services' recommended embed code.

However, each appears vertically off-line. I want both to be vertically aligned - each in the vertical center of the containing div.

Here's how they look at my site...

[image: grab]

Here is my code...

```
<div class="promos">
<div class="container">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/RobertAndrews" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large" data-dnt="true">Follow @RobertAndrews</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
    <a href="http://uk.linkedin.com/in/robertandrews"><img src="http://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_viewmy_160x33.png" width="160" height="33" border="0" alt="View Robert Andrews's profile on LinkedIn"></a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks good here: http://jsfiddle.net/R7tvx/

Answer (score 3):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DNyQR/)**

```
 a{
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Comment: without applying vertical-align: middle; its looking fine.

Comment: @C-Link  give your answer can't give answer in this comment ok

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
 .twitter-follow-button{
         vertical-align:top;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kPPHB/

also you should close your image tag

```
<img src='' />
```